# Auto-retry synchronize when connection is lost

Tags: winscp

I have an script like this:

```
open ftps://user:password@server.com -explicitssl -certificate="..."
option batch continue
mkdir remotedir
cd remotedir
lcd "local directory"
synchronize remote -criteria=size
exit
```

Everything works fine, but, if the connection is lost, WinSCP automatically `Skip`s the file which has not been uploaded correctly, as I can see in the console:

```
Copying files to remote side failed.
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip, Ski(p) all: Skip
```

Is there any option that gives `Retry` as the automatic answer? I have not been able to find it in [WinSCP option docs](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option).